# Cannot get Kendo MultiSelect to submit

Tags: asp.net, model-view-controller

I have a piece of code which seems to work but nothing is present in the Request variable at all from the drop down menu.

Here is a piece of my code:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Search", "Search"))
{
    <tr>
        <td style="padding: 5px; vertical-align: top">
            @Html.LabelFor(x => x.City, "Postort:")
        </td>
        <td style="padding: 5px; vertical-align: top">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.City)
        </td>
        <td style="padding: 5px; vertical-align: top">
            @Html.LabelFor(x => x.CMC, "CMC:")
        </td>
        <td style="padding: 5px; vertical-align: top">
            <div class="demo-section k-content">
                @(Html.Kendo().MultiSelectFor(x => x.CMC)
                      .BindTo(new SelectList(ViewBag.CMC, "UnitId", "Name"))
                      .Filter(FilterType.Contains)
                      .Placeholder("Välj ett eller flera CMC...")
                )
            </div>
        </td>
        <td style="padding: 5px">
            Visa inte matchade:<br/>
            Exakt matchning:<br/>
            Endast Aktiva:
        </td>
        <td style="padding: 5px">
            @Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.OnlyUnmatched )<br/>
            @Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.ExactMatch)<br />
            @Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.OnlyActive )<br />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="6" style="text-align: center">
            <input type="Submit" text="Sök" value="Sök" name="Sök"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

Everything else is submitted without problem. My model connection is:

```
@model ABRsite.Models.SearchABR
```

But that shouldn't matter since when I debug I get NOHTING regarding CMC at all back.
SearchABR contains a property which is a List but no dice. Nothing comes back from the request.

---

### Update:

I have made several changes, among other initialized the list inside the model object.
So, chronologically it now looks like this:

Controller:

```
    public ActionResult Search()
    {
        SearchABR searchModel = new SearchABR
        {
            CMC = new List<CMCEntity>()
        };

        return View(searchModel);
    }
```

Html:

```
            <div class="demo-section k-content">
                @(Html.Kendo().MultiSelectFor(x => x.CMC)
                      .DataSource(source =>
                      {
                          source.Read(read =>
                          {
                              read.Action("GetCMC", "Search");
                          })
                          .ServerFiltering(true);
                      })
                      .ValuePrimitive(true)
                      .DataTextField("Name")
                      .DataValueField("UnitId")
                      .Filter(FilterType.Contains)
                      .Placeholder("Välj ett eller flera CMC...")
                )
            </div>
```

Back to controller to fetch a list:

```
    public JsonResult GetCMC([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request)
    {
        RetreiveInformation ri = new RetreiveInformation();
        List<CMCEntity> lce = ri.FetchCMCInformation();
        return Json(lce, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

The CMCEntity looks like this:

```
public class CMCEntity
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int UnitID { get; set; }
}
```

And SearchABR looks (partly) like this:

```
public class SearchABR
{
    public List<CMCEntity> CMC { get; set; }
    public bool OnlyUnmatched { get; set; }
    public bool ExactMatch { get; set; }
}
```

Still cannot get it to submit.

Comment: What is the expected value type of the multiselect is it a simple array/list like List<string>() or is it a complex object like List<SomethingComplex>(), if it is simply a list of int's and strings then try setting the multiselect to `ValuePrimitive(true)`, also try setting the initial value of the Multiselect. Have you tried checking to see what is actually being sent back to the controller using either the dev "network" tools or something like fiddler?

Comment: It is not a primitive value. It's a List of object of my own design and creation. CMCEntitiy.
So the return value should be List<ABRsite.Entities.CMCEntity> to be completely correct.

Comment: I have both double and triple checked the Request with dev-tools. There is not a trace of CMC in the request. This is a post, but I have checked GET variables too, nothing. There is absolutely nothing.

Comment: Is the initial object you are binding to the control initialized? I have found that if you tried to bind a `List<T>` object to a control that is null then the value isn't always sent back. If the multiselect is being used to gather `id's` bind the control to a simple list like `List<int>', `list<Guid>` and then return that back as the view model.

Comment: Good thinking, I really thought you were onto something but sadly that didn't work.

Comment: If you are setting `ValuePrimitive` the control will only post back the `Value` list  so in your case `List<int>` not your complex object. http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/multiselect#configuration-valuePrimitive (see for further details)

Comment: I have thought about that and tried both with ValuePrimitive to false, true and not present. Still, nothing is sent to the function in the controller.

Comment: The only other thing I can suggest at this stage is also set the value of the control when it is initially created eg. `.Value(@Model.CMC)`  one thing I have noticed is that you may have a typo between the control and the `dataValueField` expression. in the model you are using `UnitID` but in the control you are binding to `UnitId` this could be the source of your problem here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem had nothing to do with anything with the MultiSelect or the MVC coding. The actual problem was the

```
@using(Html.BeginForm...
```

as you can see this tag is located inside a table which is illegal.
So when I moved the start of the using outside the start of the table and the end of the using to outside the end of the table it worked.